# Boundedness of Fourier Transform on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

> Let $f$ be of moderate decrease, i.e., there exists $A>0$ such that $f(x)\le \frac{A}{1+x^2}$ for all $x$. Then we can define the Fourier Transform by
> $$\hat{f}(\xi):= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx.$$
> Of course, $|e^{-2\pi ix\xi}|=1$ so the integrand is of moderate decrease and the integral makes sense. **In fact, this last observation implies that $\hat{f}$ is bounded.**

I'm trying to show this part. I know that we have

$$\left|\int_{-N}^Nf(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi} dx\right|\le 2N\frac{A}{1+x^2}$$

because the integrand is of moderate decrease, but if we make $N\to\infty$ to get $\hat f$ on the LHS, the RHS also goes to infinity, so I don't know how to use the fact of the integrand being of moderate decrease to show the boundedness of $\hat f$.

Comment: The value of that integral depends on $\xi$ and $N$, not on $x$. What is the lower bound on $f$?

Comment: Your bound needs to be a little more delicate. Since $x$ is a variable of integration, it is truly meaningless outside.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake in writing the bound of the integral using the bound of the function. As $f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\le \frac{A}{1+x^2}$, we have $\int_{-N}^Nf(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi} dx\le\int\frac{A}{1+x^2}dx=2A\arctan(N)$. Then taking $N\to\infty$ we have $\hat f(\xi)\le A\pi$, because $\arctan(N)\to\pi/2$. That sounds right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\hat{f}(\xi)| \le \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)| dx \le A \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx \:.$$ From this you get the result because the integral on the right hand side is finite.